# How to get speed from sumo's map.rou.xml file using tracimobility?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I have to get the speed from the map.rou.xml file which used in sumo, i am connecting sumo with omnet using veins_inet, so how can i get the speed from this file to use it in the udpbasicapp using tracimobility.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get speed from sumo's map.rou.xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911697/how-to-get-speed-from-sumos-map-rou-xml-file)

Comment: The old question has been deleted, i have seen that we have tracimobility in the new versions of veins so it's different, not to read xml, we have tracimobility how to use it to get the speed. @thardes2

Comment: Different versions of Veins differ in how they are used. Which version of Veins are you using?

Comment: I'am using veins version 4.7.1 @ChristophSommer

Comment: Are you asking how you can programmatically obtain the maximum speed of a lane in the road network? This can be done using Lane::getMaxSpeed from TraCICommandInterface, written in file https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.7.1/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h#L134

Comment: @ChristophSommer i have to get the speed in the udpbasicapp.cc i'am using this app how can i use the speed in the udpbasicapp.cc